# AJAX load function not working with some requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that allows users to add a server domain to a database.

Before it is added to the db it is checked to see if that server/domain is up or down. After it is inserted into the database I use the php header function to redirect back to a php page that gets a list of the servers through the jQuery load function. The problem is that when a server is down (times out), when it redirects back to the page with the load function, it doesn't load the list of servers.

The script below is present on the page, as well as the target div. When I check through the Chrome console it doesn't show that any requests to server_list are being made.

How I'm loading the server list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#server_table").load("server_list.php #servers");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
            $("#server_table").load("server_list.php #servers");
        }, 3000);

    });
</script>
```

Again, this works the majority of the time, with no changes to the code. So I have no idea why when a server is down, nothing shows on the page.

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome!

Edit to Add: When the load function doesn't work, if I reload the page by clicking reload, it works properly (down servers/domains included). If I just refresh the page by clicking in the URL bar and pressing enter, it does not work.

Comment: a little confused, but browser caching comes to mind. i would switch from `load`, to `ajax`, so you have more options then add `cache: false`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the php is blocking while trying to connect to a server, therefore subsequent ajax requests do not get a response.

Check your developer console net tab to see what happens after 3 seconds, does it get a response or does it timeout?

You can sometimes prevent php from blocking by doing a `session_write_close();` session variables will still be readable and you can then run php scripts simultaneously